# Clojure spec for vector of map with indeterminate number of keys

Tags: testing, clojure, specifications, leiningen, clojure.spec

I am trying to write a clojure spec for a function that takes the following two maps as parameters.

```
{1 BL0-MD0-SU, 0 BL0-SM0-SU}
{0 [https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmcLjsUDHVuy8GPUPmj4ZdGa3FWTfGnsKhWZ4dxqUaGGXk/doge.jpg ], 1 [https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmcLjsUDHVuy8GPUPmj4ZdGa3FWTfGnsKhWZ4dxqUaGGXk/doge.jpg ]}
```

Each map can have a varying length, dependent on how many tshirts a user wishes to purchase. I am unsure how to write a spec for this, that allows for the number of keys and values in each map to vary. Also it would be useful if I could assert that each of the maps contain the same number of keys.

EDIT:

The spec should also passed when the following is passed:

```
{1 BL0-MD0-SU, 0 BL0-SM0-SU, 2 BL0-LG0-SU}
{0 [https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmcLjsUDHVuy8GPUPmj4ZdGa3FWTfGnsKhWZ4dxqUaGGXk/doge.jpg ], 1 [https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmcLjsUDHVuy8GPUPmj4ZdGa3FWTfGnsKhWZ4dxqUaGGXk/doge.jpg ], 2 [ ]}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(s/def ::arg1 (s/map-of long? string?))
(s/def ::arg2 (s/map-of long? vector?))
(s/def ::args (s/and (s/cat :arg1 ::arg1 :arg2 ::arg2)
                     (fn [{:keys [arg1 arg2]}]
                       (= (count arg1) (count arg2)))))
```

If you need to attach this spec to a function, you can learn how to do it here: https://clojure.org/guides/spec#_specing_functions

Comment: Will this implementation not fail if there were additional keys in the maps?

Comment: What Eugene's spec is saying is: the function takes two parameters.  The first parameter is a map of long to string and the second parameter is a map from long to a vector.  And, the number of keys in the first map is the same as the number of keys in the second map.  That is independent of the actual number of keys.